# login page asp.net sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, authentication

I have this code and need to complete it..

```
string conn_str = 
     @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;
       Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE UserName=@un", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@un",  SqlDbType.NVarChar);

cmd.Parameters["@un"].Value = **???**;

conn.Open();
string pwd = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

I have some values in sql data:
Tables:
    Users
          Username
          Password

Now in login page i have textboxNAME and textboxPassword and if user type right login info(that in database) it refers him to default.aspx

Comment: instead do a ``select count(1) from users where username=@username and password = @password`` and make sure the password is hashed with salt. then with executescalar as you are using now, see if the value is > 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cmd.Parameters["@un"].Value = textboxName.Text;
```

and

```
if(textboxPassword.Text.Equals(pwd))
{
    Request.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
else
{
//login failed
}
```

Comment: Does a parameter length need to be set somewhere?

Comment: ok, but after `cmd.Parameters["@un"].Value = textboxName.Text;`

Comment: @RaShe this kind of redirection will work but it not secure at all. Look into [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) to make it secure.

Comment: @Martin I don't know of any parameter length that needs to be set.

Comment: @Bala R it's just an exercise in my school, I never studied sql and have problems with it..

Comment: @Bala R are u sure it's `if(textboxPassword.Text.**Equals**(pwd))` coz it's not working:)

Comment: Yeah!. Try to put a breakpoint on the line with the if statement to see what `textboxPassword.Text` and `pwd` are.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string conn_str = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;        Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"; 

private string _password;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE UserName=@un", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@un",  SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value=txtusername.text;  
//use add with value to specify which object you want to use

SqlDataAdapter adapt =  new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

//load data to datatable
DataTable dt = new Datatable();

conn.Open(); 

adapt.Fill(dt);

//get Password on Datatable
Foreach(DataRow a in dt.Rows)
{

  _password = a["Password"].Tostring();

}

//Check password
if(_password==string.Empty)
{
//remain 
}
else if(_password==txtpassword.Text)
{
Response.Redirect("My page");
}

 conn.Close();
```

Regards